# Why can't I create a 1 to many relationship without a primary key?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I've been messing with the Design view of my DBML class for hours now.  I have one class, call it A, that has a 1 to many relationship with B, C, D, and E.  In the generated code I can see that Class A has generated

```
private EntitySet<BB> _bb;
private EntitySet<CC> _cc;
private EntitySet<EE> _ee;
```

But it hasn't generated one for D.  Finally for giggles I added a primary key to D; all the other classes had one except for D; and NOW it's generating a EntitySet _dd.  But why is this?  I don't need that table to have a specified primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using LINQ to SQL due to the .dbml files. LINQ to SQL (and Entity Framework to some degree) struggle with tables that do not contain primary keys. Specifically, the table needs a primary key to implement INotifyPropertyChanged (the interface that tracks changes for a specific identity... how can an entity be tracked if it does not have a primary key?). A good example of why this is needed can be found here.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3b216d2-fa06-49a1-a901-11702e80b38c/linq-to-sql-table-doesnt-have-primary-key?forum=linqtosql

As a follow up, is there a specific reason why the table does not have a primary key? Does it not represent a entity in your data model? If it is a "lookup" table perhaps you can wrap the functionality in a stored procedure and then call the stored procedure via LINQ to SQL.